# Why is closing a terminal window and opening a new one sometimes the solution?

Tags: command-line

Sometimes when I'm debugging a program that runs from the command line, a seemingly obvious change doesn't work until I close the terminal window, open a new one, and try again. I've had this happen on both Mac OS (i.e., bash) and Windows.

This is a last-ditch thing I do when obvious solutions fail, but I'd like to know why. Is it something about the command-line program "capturing" a snapshot of something when it's created?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it could have to do with remembering which executable a command name refers to, e.g. if you've been using `/usr/bin/foo` and then create `/usr/local/bin/foo`, the shell might not see the latter. (though somehow I feel this isn't it).

Comment: `hash -r` is a less drastic fix for that in Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shells can hash known binaries (so they don't have to search the path for it)

When changing system wide environment variables, you need to start a new shell to get the new environment. Note that just entering a subshell doesn't work as child processes inherit their environments from their parents

Comment: Can somebody expand on "Shells can hash known binaries"? I know what hashing is; is it somehow used when a command is about to be exeucted?

Comment: _When changing system wide environment variables, you need to start a new shell to get the new environment._ Okay, that is what I was thinking. Can anyone say more about **why** you need to start a new shell? Is there a reason why the shell _can't_ be aware of the current state of all environment variables? Thanks.

Comment: @Gregg: partly just by definition; UNIX has a long heritage like that. It's primary uses are security: prevent manipulation of environment to prevent compromising PATH/LIBPATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc. that could be used to get untrusted code to execute. By extension, it serves to isolate processes: some processes will _require_ a custom PATH etc. and they simply would not work correctly if child processes somehow started from 'the _new_ global environment' because they depend on the same environment as their parent(s)